# How to build .NET Core 3.1 console app with win-x64 runtime on linux using only local package source?

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-sdk

I have a special use-case where I need to be able to build a clean repository when I'm offline. I'm allowed to attach a local nuget feed and have a standard docker image locally available.

The build container is based on linux.

The solution I'm looking at involves preparing the local nuget feed with a dotnet restore, and then inside the linux container perform dotnet build with a specified nuget source.

I am building for the win-x64 runtime.

**Environment:**

```
$ dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.302
 Commit:    41faccf259

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     alpine
 OS Version:  3.12
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         linux-musl-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.302/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.6
  Commit:  3acd9b0cd1

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.302 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

**Expected result:**

A successful build inside the docker linux container.

**Actual result:**

`error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64. No packages exist with this id in source(s): local`

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. **On development machine (Win10 1909, with dotnet SDK 3.1.302):**

   1. `mkdir dotnetTest`
   2. `cd dotnetTest`
   3. `dotnet new console`
   4. `dotnet restore --runtime win-x64 --packages $pwd\nuget`
   5. At this point the nuget folder contains the following (since this is only a minimal example):

      1. `microsoft.aspnetcore.app.runtime.win-x64`
      2. `microsoft.netcore.app.runtime.win-x64`
      3. `microsoft.windowsdesktop.app.runtime.win-x64`
   6. `` docker run --rm -it -v $pwd`:/repo -v $pwd\nuget`:/nuget mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1.302-alpine3.12 ``
2. **Inside docker container:**

   1. `dotnet nuget disable source nuget.org`
   2. `dotnet nuget add source /nuget --name local`
   3. `cd repo`
   4. `dotnet build --runtime win-x64`

The last command results in this:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
/repo/dotnetTest.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64. No packages exist with this id in source(s): local
  Failed to restore /repo/dotnetTest.csproj (in 988 ms).

Build FAILED.

/repo/dotnetTest.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64. No packages exist with this id in source(s): local
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

The interresting part highlighted: `error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64. No packages exist with this id in source(s): local`

I should also mention that starting a new container and just running `cd repo` followed by `dotnet build --runtime win-x64` works without issues (the missing `Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64` is apperantly downloaded).

**Tested workaround:**

I have tried to use the `"-p:DisableImplicitNuGetFallbackFolder=true"` when doing dotnet restore on the developer machine:
`dotnet restore --runtime win-x64 --packages $pwd\nuget "-p:DisableImplicitNuGetFallbackFolder=true"`.

No difference in the result in this case.

**Possible workaround:**

Prepare the local nuget feed from within a (another) docker container instead of directly on the development computer. This is however extra complicated and should be avoided if not needed (it may be needed?).

**Questions:**

1. Should it be possible to build a win-x64 console app from Linux with a local nuget feed prepared from a Windows machine (my approach above)?
2. Any other workarounds or guideance to accomplish what I try to do?